Health Check is not working for Console Application
NET, I have referred these links to implement health checks for a console application [non HTTP based]:

Performing a health check in .NET Core Worker Service
.NET Core Workerservice - how to provide a health check endpoint without HTTP?

Question
when I run my console application, I see a new file created in TEMP folder. even after letting the application run for 5 mins. the last modified datetime of that file is not changed.
My expectation is health check would run every 5 secs and would update/modify the file, based on minute of the time.
now I doubt if PublishAsync method is working as expected. let me know where am I going wrong ?
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
                Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                    .UseWindowsService()
                    .UseSystemd()
                    .ConfigureLogging(ConfigureLogging)
                    .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, configApp) =>
                    {
                        var environmentName = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("env").ToLower();
                        Console.WriteLine("ENV Variable Code is " + environmentName);
                        ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["EnvType"] = environmentName;
                        configApp
                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.json", true)
                            .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{environmentName}.json", true);
                    })
                    .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                    {
                        var container = InjectionContainer.Initialize(services);
                        services.AddHostedService(service =>
                        {
                            var worker = container.GetInstance<Worker>();
                            return worker;
                        });
                        services.AddHealthChecks()
                        .AddCheck("test", () => DateTime.UtcNow.Minute % 2 == 0 ? HealthCheckResult.Healthy() : HealthCheckResult.Unhealthy());

                        services.AddSingleton<IHealthCheckPublisher, HealthCheckPublisher>();
                        services.Configure<HealthCheckPublisherOptions>(options =>
                        {
                            options.Delay = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                            options.Period = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                        });
                    })
                    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                    {
                        webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                    });

            
        }

Health check publisher
public class HealthCheckPublisher : IHealthCheckPublisher
{
    private readonly string _fileName;
    private HealthStatus _prevStatus = HealthStatus.Unhealthy;

    public HealthCheckPublisher()
    {
        _fileName =  Path.GetTempFileName();
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Creates / touches a file on the file system to indicate "healtyh" (liveness) state of the pod
    /// Deletes the files to indicate "unhealthy"
    /// The file will then be checked by k8s livenessProbe
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="report"></param>
    /// <param name="cancellationToken"></param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public Task PublishAsync(HealthReport report, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var fileExists = _prevStatus == HealthStatus.Healthy;

        if (report.Status == HealthStatus.Healthy)
        {
            using var _ = File.Create(_fileName);
        }
        else if (fileExists)
        {
            File.Delete(_fileName);
        }

        _prevStatus = report.Status;

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}


Inside the console , do you see multiple unhealth error inside it? Based on your codes, it works on my side. It works well.

@Brando Zhang I added few console statements in side the PublishAsync method, nothing is printed on to the console window.
Time modified for the file in TEMP folder is the time I run the .exe. even after waiting for few mins lastModifiedTime is not updated for that TEMP file.
Not sure if this approach is correct, I tried adding a break point inside PublishAsync method and the break point is not hit !
